# Optimize the FFT calculation in C++ without creating even/odd arrays

Tags: c++, lookup

Here is my code:

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
 
void FFT(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];
    FFT(even);
    FFT(odd);
    
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
    
}
```

As you can see Cooley-Tukey FFT approach is divide and conquer algorithm. But in each iteration, we are creating new arrays even/odd. Even if I tried the use directly give the slicing parts as FFT arguments like `FFT(x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)])`, it does not work. What I want is, use directly the index values for even and odd part rather creating them, which are more memory-expensive.

Moreover,
In the for loop, there is the part,

```
Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N) * odd[k];
```

How to optimize this to use a lookup table or precomputed values.

Comment: Considering how common the algo is, you can just google it, and someone already wrote an implementation. Pretty much the first result I got https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fft.html#improved-implementation-in-place-computation

Comment: Your title says "without creating even/odd arrays", but the code has arrays called `even` and `odd`.  Can you explain the discrepancy for us?  At the moment, it looks like the code isn't functioning __as intended__, which is a requirement for review to begin.

Comment: Of course, that's the general implementation of Cooley-Tukey algorithm. It holds the memory for the even and odd part, where I do not intend. Hope to clear now.

Comment: @TobySpeight he asks how to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoiding allocating extra arrays

You can't avoid allocating extra arrays if you use this particular FFT method. While with C++23 you could pass views and use  [`std::ranges::stride_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/stride_view), the problem is that you are modifying the array in the last part of `FFT()`. If you would directly modify the original array, a higher level of recursion will corrupt the array for the lower levels of recursion.

You can do an in-place FFT transform though using bit-reversed counters, see [this article](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fft.html#improved-implementation-in-place-computation) that ALX23z mentioned.

## Precalculate the roots of unity

> How to optimize this to use a lookup table or precomputed values.

Yes, just do that. You can split your function into two:

```
static void FFT_internal(CArray& x, CArray& roots, ...)
{
    … 
    Complex t = roots[k * roots.size() / x.size()] * odd[k];
    …
}

void FFT(CArray& x)
{
    CArray roots;
    roots.reserve(x.size());

    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < x.size(); ++k) {
        roots.push_back(std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N));
    }

    FFT_internal(x, roots);
}
```

Of course, if you are going to call `FFT()` often with the same size array, then that still is wasted effort, and you should explicitly have the caller precalculate the roots once, and then reuse those values for every call to `FFT()`.

Note that it is also possible to recursively calculate those roots, and you can reuse your existing recursive structure for this. I don't think it will gain you any performance though.

## Avoid the `typedef`s

While a `typedef` is handy in several situations, don't use it just to avoid some typing on your keyboard. Creating an abbreviation makes it harder for someone else to understand what the actual type is. Often, you can use `auto` to avoid having to write a type explicitly. For example:

```
void FFT(std::valarray<std::complex<double>>& x)
{
    …
    auto even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    auto  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];
    …
    auto t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N) * odd[k];
    …
}
```